# HTA - Pass parameter from hyperlink to WPF application

Tags: wpf, syntax, hyperlink, arguments, hta

**Requirement**
I'm trying to use an HTA, or anything at this point, as a go-between between a clicked hyperlink and a WPF application (`WPF_App.exe`) I have, since we need to send it whatever ID that is on that hyperlink (which will be pre-staged by another application) in order to bring up a particular item within the WPF app.

**What I've Done**
I have the following HTML I've saved as `test.hta` that can accept a querystring parameter `AppID` and parse it.  It can then be sent to a WPF application, which is being started using a Wscript.Shell object:

```
<html><head>
<script language="VBScript">
Sub RunProgram(param)
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "\\our_network_share\some_folder\WPF_App.exe " & param
    Me.Close
End Sub
</script>

<script language ="Javascript">
function callVB () {
    var param = getParameterByName('AppID');
    RunProgram(param);
}

function getParameterByName(name) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:callVB()">
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem to Resolve**
Even though I can call this HTA using `file://our_network_share/some_folder/test.hta?AppID=100` in IE or Windows Explorer and it will pass the WPF app the ID correctly, **it will not work from a hyperlink this way** (the link must be created in Outlook using Ctrl+K and use Ctrl+Click to test, since the link will be placed into e-mails... Word is also a good test of this, and also fails, so far), and we need to be able to link to this HTA file from an e-mail while providing a parameter.  Can this be done?  And I'm not locked into this HTA, just it was the closest I've gotten so far.

**Things I've Tried**
I've looked at how you can [pass command line arguments to an HTA](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/04/20/how-can-i-pass-command-line-variables-to-an-hta-when-it-starts/), but is there a way to pass a parameter from a hyperlink to an HTA in a querystring?  The reason for a querystring is so far I'm not seeing how you can resolve spaces between the HTA file name and the parameter, or the WPF name and parameter for that matter, in a hyperlink.  Putting in the HTML code `%20` doesn't work, nor does putting quotes around the file link and arguments.  Maybe it's just a syntax issue at this point, but not sure what it would be.

Answer (score -1):

For security reasons, I don't think Outlook will allow you to trigger a shell program or command line by clicking on a hyperlink in the email. That is to protect the user from malicious attacks.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know you can do this with hyperlinks to web pages-like in your normal e-mail. An HTA can parse a link the same way if the app is local, e.g. `file:///C:\temp\test.hta?AppID=1`, and it will launch with that argument passed in (if `WPF_App.exe` is put in the same folder and `objShell.Run` is updated to that location). Just if I put the file on a network share (along with `WFP_App.exe` and update `objShell.Run`) and reference it with `file:///\\our_network_share\some_folder\test.hta?AppID=1`, the ID gets passed in as null. The app will launch, just the ID is null.